# Passing information to website

Tags: c#, php, html

I am working on a website that displays information about an application in C#.
What I would like to achieve is that whenever someone for example click a button in the application the website adds 1 to button clicks.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not looking to build something totally from scratch, you could look into using googles measurement protocol. Although it does not allow the collection of user specific data, tracking button clicks or other application actions is what it's meant for.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

The measurement protocol will take care of the data collection and storage of your application events and the data could be viewed using the standard Google Analytics interface; helpful for testing. Then if you wanted to display the collected analytics on your custom website you could use the [reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).

Comment: Please do not answer overly broad questions such as the one asked here.